# How to stop SPAM in my GMail account?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I have this stupid friend of mine who is giving me a lot of pain these days. He is registering  my profile and putting up my Email ID along with my phone no. on the worst spam sites on the web. These sites sadly do not require any confirmation or anything. I've got more spam in the last couple of weeks than in the last 5 years. What should I do? How can I stop it.

I have started filtering all the mails and delete them directly. But it's not helping much. Sometimes I also report phishing. Should I start marking it as spam?

Moreover there are a few sites like this one called the monster.com which are a real pain in the neck. I cannot create a filter for them because the mails which I receive are something like this:

From: team1@career-links.com via mint1.monster.co.inmonster.co.in

When I create filter for such mails, only "team1@career-links.com" gets selected. Sadly this part keeps on changing. Even "mint1.monster.co.in" changes but the change only takes place in the integer attached with mint. So its like mint&&.monster.co.in. So the monster.co.in part remains same. How can I exploit this fact?

Comment: I would report that friend and mark him as spam.

Comment: I have heard of unsolicited mails through these email addresses from many people, and narrowed this down to a job portal called MonsterIndia.com. You should a) change your preferences to get no promotional mails, b) deactivate your account there, or c) report them - depending on the level of your inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

My advice is to report email as SPAM, as Gmail has a pretty efficient engine at detecting SPAM once it knows your habits. Another option is to use Filters and Labels to sort mail which is directly addressed to you, so you can identify them easier. But the efficiency of the latter depends much on how the SPAM is sent.

To set up a filter to remove `*@monster.co.in`, go to Settings > Filters > Create New Filter and put `monster.co.in` in the From field, and then tell it to move the selected emails to the trash, or mark them as SPAM.

Comment: This solution doesn't work to block future emails, even those from the same sending address. Gmail needs to either automatically send designated e-mail address spam to trash and block future e-mails or to set a user adjustable time for automatically sending spam to trash. It doesn't do this and and doesn't have a system to purge the spam folder after a certain time period. This is a huge pain in the derriere to constantly go into the spam folder, check, and delete all of the crap they allow through!! At least Hotmail has a time limit and then purges, but it suffers from constantly reinserting

Comment: I am not sure I get your point. First, you can send the unwanted mail to trash using a filter (with wildcards for unknown addresses from known spamming domains), second GMail clearly mentions that "(messages that have been in Spam more than 30 days will be automatically deleted)". Admittedly this is not configurable, but it does what one needs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the alias as the main e-mail, and filter out the rest.
E.g. if your friend is spamming you on namesurname@, use name.surname@ as your default email (change in your profiles, etc.).

You can also use + sign, like: example+nospam@ to do the similar thing.

See: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12096

Answer (score -2):

I have reduced to almost not receiving spam messages in my gmail account by moving them into the trash folder instead of deleting them.  If spams were deleted from the spam folder, they were moved automatically to the trash folder but also turned as read messages.  Moving spams to trash kept the unread mark and can proceed to delete  without notifying to hackers that these were read.  It worked in my IPhone and IPad but have not tried in my laptop.  Good luck!

Comment: How do you think "hackers" would see messages as being read? What difference do you think this would make?

Comment: Nobody from the outside knows how you mark your emails.